# Error simplifying methods and ordering by Id in Java8 - Collectors

Tags: java, arraylist, java-8, hashmap

I have the following methods almost the same and very similar:

```
public static Map<String, Long> countTotalCities(List<OrderData> orderDataList) {
    return orderDataList.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                    OrderData::getCity,
                    Collectors.counting()));
}

public static Map<String, Long> countTotalType(List<OrderData> orderDataList) {
    return orderDataList.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                    OrderData::getType,
                    Collectors.counting()));
}

public static Map<String, Long> countTotalChannels(List<OrderData> orderDataList) {
    return orderDataList.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                    OrderData::getChannel,
                    Collectors.counting()));
}
```

The getCity, getType, and getChannel methods are of type String.
Is there a way to put these 3 methods in 1 method and pass a String parameter to the method for simplicity. I want to have 1 single method instead of 3. 
I've even thought that I could have the same map for all results.
I want to do something like this:

```
public static Map<String, Long> countTotalResults(List<OrderData> orderDataList, String field) {
    return orderDataList.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(field,Collectors.counting()));
}
```

But I get the following compilation error when I try to do this: Collectors.groupingBy(field,...)

This is the error shown:
reason: no instance(s) of type variable(s) K, T exist so that String conforms to Function

I also want to sort these results into an OrderId. I don't know how to indicate this order in Java 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method can take just a `Function<OrderData, String>`:

```
public static Map<String, Long> countTotalResults(List<OrderData> orderDataList, 
         Function<OrderData, String> mapper) {
    return orderDataList.stream()
            .sorted(Comparator.comparingLong(OrderData::getOrderId))
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(mapper,Collectors.counting()));
}
```

Which will allow you to call with the same method references:

```
countTotalResults(list, OrderData::getCity);
countTotalResults(list, OrderData::getType);
countTotalResults(list, OrderData::getChannel);
```

Comment: Ok, this works. Amazing. Thank you. But I also need to sort these results by an OrderId. This is what is missing.
How can I sort these results by an orderId?
This question is in the last line of my post above.
Thank you.

Comment: What's the data type of `orderId`?

Comment: orderId is of type long.
This is what I'm missing.
I need to order the result by orderId (long)

Comment: I've edited. If you want to make the comparison field dynamic too, you may want to take in a `Comparator<OrderData>` and pass the argument to `sorted()`

Answer (score 2):

The [`groupingBy()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy(java.util.function.Function,java.util.stream.Collector)) accepts as first argument a `Function` that maps an `OrderData` as a `String` (regarding your `Map` here) so that's the type of parameter you need to have in the signature :

```
... countTotalResults(List<OrderData> orderDataList, Function<OrderData, String> classifier)
```

Then to call it, give it the function:

- as method reference

  ```
  countTotalResults(someList, OrderData::getChannel);
  ```
- as lambda

  ```
  countTotalResults(null, o -> o.getChannel());
  ```

---

The whole method including the `sorting` part

```
public static Map<String, Long> countTotalResults(List<OrderData> orderDataList, Function<OrderData, String> classifier) {
    return orderDataList.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparingLong(OrderData::getOrderId))
                                 .collect(groupingBy(classifier, counting()));
}
```

Comment: Ok, this works. Amazing. Thank you. But I also need to sort these results by an OrderId. This is what is missing.
How can I sort these results by an orderId?
This question is in the last line of my post above.
Thank you.

Comment: orderId is of type long. This is what I'm missing. I need to order the result by orderId (long)

Comment: @Javi I've just edit, you can provide a Comparator instance like this, or a lambda `.sorted((o1, o2) -> Long.compare(o1.getOrderId(), o2.getOrderId()))`

Comment: @Javi You may now think about [accepting an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)